# Watermark changed in admin still has default magento watermark

Tags: configuration, design

I changed the watermark image in admin. It is applied for both the default and site level. The magento watermark still applies even after clearing cache. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: You should clear the images cache. The images that were already generated before you changed the watermark are still on the disk and Magento is using them. This can be done from `System->Cache Management`

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, how?

Comment: No just about to flush image cache. Will let you know when I figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Many people confuse `Product Image Watermarks` with `Product Image Placeholders`.

[image: Difference]

Product Image Watermarks can be changed from

`System > Configuration > Design > Product Image Watermarks`

Product Image Placeholders can be changed from

`System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders`

Answer (score -1):

Check this folder as well to make sure its clear:
media/catalog/product/cache/

Comment: You should elaborate.